# Return unique values from a column with multiple values per field

Tags: php, mysql, explode, array-unique

I have a database table with a column where multiple strings are stored in each field, separated by a ;

I need to get a list of all unique values in that column.  I know there has to be an easier way to do this, but I can't find my answer anywhere. Here is what I'm doing so far:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT column FROM modx_scripture_table WHERE column!=''", $con);

$filter_all = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $filter_all[] = $row;
}

 function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
} 
$filter_flat = array_flatten($filter_all);


function array_explode($array) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array  as  $key => $value) {
  $result[$key] = explode(';',$value); 
  }
  return $result;
}


$filter_sploded = array_explode($filter_flat);

$filter_full = array_flatten($filter_sploded);

$filter_final = array_unique($filter_full);

print_r($filter_final);
```

Everything seems to be working except the array_unique.  I'm still getting duplicate strings in $filter_final.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting unique values if you are executing directly on the server?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to programming.  Isn't php always processed server-side?  I'm not sure what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

After exploding the string use `array_unique()` for fnding unique values in an array.

Example:

```
$arr=array('1','2','3','4','5','3','1');
print_r(array_unique($arr));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => 4
[4] => 5
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but please read my original post more closely.  I am already using array_unique.  My problem is that it is not working.